# Sending feed back from website to any email

Tags: html, forms

i want to include a text field called feed back and a button called submit in my html page.
now how to redirect this feed back entered by user of my site to my business email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the built in HTML form tags, [take a look at this example.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail)

Just change `action="MAILTO:someone@example.com"` to include your business email address instead.